# Storing database results to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store the result from a MySQL statement for later use in PHP. I have this code which gets me the result:

```
// Get the categories from the db.
$categories = array();
$catSql = "SELECT id, name FROM categories";
if ($catStmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $catSql)) 
{
    $catStmt->execute();
    $result = $catStmt->get_result();
    // Fetch the result variables.
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        // Store the results for later use.
    }
}
```

So I know i will have the results in `$row["id"]` and `$row["name"]` and I want to save all of the rows so whenever i need them i can loop through them and for example echo them. I have searched for structures and arrays for keeping them in PHP but I cannot seem to find any information about that or maybe I am not searching in the right direction. Can anyone point me where i should read about this to find out how to do this efficiently and if possible post a small example?

Comment: If you use `fetch_all()` it will give you an array that you can loop through over and over again. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "keeping" them?  Do you want the result to persist across multiple requests?

Comment: Yes, I would like the result to persist across multiple requests, if that is possible.

Comment: Do some research on sessions then.

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Comment: You are already persisting the data in the database? Why do you want to use yet another storage medium?

Comment: How else would you keep the data across multiple requests? Fetch the data from the database on every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

// Get the categories from the db.
$categories = array();
$catSql = "SELECT id, name FROM categories";
if ($catStmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $catSql)) 
{
    $catStmt->execute();
    $result = $catStmt->get_result();
    // Fetch the result variables.
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        // Store the results for later use.
        $_SESSION['category_' . $row['id']] = $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Then access it later from a different page

```
$_SESSION['session_variable_name']
```

You can also create an array of the information and store the entire array in a single session variable.

Just make sure you add the session_start function at the beginning of each page. The if statement prevents you from trying to start it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = array();
$catSql = "SELECT id, name FROM categories";
if ($catStmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $catSql)) 
{
    $catStmt->execute();
    $result = $catStmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $categories[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
    }
}
```

And If you want the name anywhere use below :

```
$categories[$id]
```

Comment: This will not persist the data.

Comment: use `fetch_all()` insted of `fetch_assoc()`.